# How to avoid bad SEO duplicated content URLs in Zend Framework

Tags: seo, duplicates, zend-framework

I'm pretty new to Zend Framework and I'm building a website hoping to implement good SEO practices.

The URL structure will be:
`example.com/language/city/controller/action`

So I've created this route in my bootstrap:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $front->getRouter();
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':language/:city/:controller/:action/*',
                                         array('language'=>'es',
                                               'city'=>'barcelona',
                                               'controller'=>'index',
                                               'action'=>'index'));
$router->addRoute('language_city', $route);
```

Which I'm not sure is OK but seems to do the trick.

What I notice next is all these URLs point to the same content (bad SEO practice):

`/`
`/es`
`/es/barcelona`
`/es/barcelona/index`
`/es/barcelona/index/index`

Is there a way to get around this duplicated content problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the defaults, so for exactly one page (the default page) the request will be the same. It you removed the defaults, you'll get an error (`404` I believe) if the URI doesn't contain the variable.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':language/:city/:controller/:action/*',
    array('language'=>'es', //default when not in URI
          'city'=>'barcelona', //default when not in URI
          'controller'=>'index', //default when not in URI
          'action'=>'index' //default when not in URI
    )
 );
```

It seems like you may want to **remove the defaults for** `language` `city`, since without that data I'm not sure what your controller is going to do.

If you did that, the only 'duplicated' URIs will be:

```
/es/barcelona
/es/barcelona/index
/es/barcelona/index/index
```

But **you only have to use one of those URIs**. If you output links using Zend's `View_Helper_Url`, it'll drop the `index/index` off - since it matches the default value.

You can always add additional routes to map other requests (say `/`) to the relevant controller.

It should also be noted, **if you only have a single controller handling all these 'city' requests, you don't need to put it on the URI**:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':language/:city/:action/*',
    array('language'=>'es', //default when not in URI
          'city'=>'barcelona', //default when not in URI
          'controller'=>'index', //all requests route here
          'action'=>'index' //default when not in URI
    )
 );
```

Then the only 'duplicate' URIs are:

```
/es/barcelona
/es/barcelona/index
```

Comment: @XeL Glad to help - might be worth taking a look at the various router types. If you're doing basic CRUD, I find the REST router useful.